# swift unrecognized selector for target action pattern

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to use a gesture recognizer in swift but I keep getting an unrecognized selector crash.

```
init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    self.addGestureRecognizer(tapRecognizer)
    tapRecognizer.addTarget(self, action:"respondToTap:")

    self.userInteractionEnabled = true
}

func respondToTap(#recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer!)-> Void {
    switch recognizer.state {

    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
        showTouchDown()

    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended:
        showTouchUp()

    default:
        return
    }
}
```

How do a use a method signature in swift for target-action stuff?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By defining your function as `func respondToTap(#recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer!)`, you're giving the first parameter an [external name](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_214). So your method is actually called `respondToTaprecognizer:`. You don't want the parameter to have an external name, it should be `func respondToTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer!)`.

Answer (score 0):

interesting. It was using the # in my parameter name.